# Leaflet.js displaying incomplete base map

Tags: leaflet, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am working on a tile server with a `leaflet.js` UI. I have successfully created the tiles for my base map and the tiles for the overlay. The result can be seen [here](http://cendas.lamce.coppe.ufrj.br/Mapea/) (zoom in further to see overlay). Unfortunately, as can be observed, the base map is incomplete and is wrapping in a weird way. This is not the result of a fault tiling process I believe as I am using the same tile hierarchy [here](http://cendas.lamce.coppe.ufrj.br/tiles/natural/), using `openlayers.js`. As you can see, in that UI, the base map is complete.

This is my current leaflet interface:

```html
<html>
    <title>Mapea - Mapeamento Meoteorológica Inteligente</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/map.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/L.Control.MousePosition.css"  />
    <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/L.Control.MousePosition.js" /></script>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var base = 'natural';
            var natural = L.tileLayer('../tiles/'+ base + '/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Mapa &copy; NaturalEarth2',
                maxZoom: 5,
                tms: true
            });
            var wind = L.tileLayer('../tiles/wind/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Dado de vento &copy; Aquamet',
                maxZoom: 5,
                tms: true
            });
            var oc = L.tileLayer('../tiles/oc/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Dado de clorofila &copy; Aquamet',
                maxZoom: 9,
                tms: true
            });

            var map = L.map('map', {
                center: new L.LatLng(0, 0),
                zoom: 1,
                layers: [natural,wind]
            });

            var baselayers = {
                Natural: natural
            }
            var datalayers = {
                Vento: wind,
                Clorofila: oc
            }
            L.control.layers(baselayers, datalayers).addTo(map);
            L.control.mousePosition().addTo(map);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Although I doubt this has to anything to do with the tiling process, as I wrote the following based on this [google tutorial][3], here is my tiling script.*

- Sorry, I could not post the link directly, I'm new to this stackexchange.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
##
## tiler: creates tiled hierarchy from an ungeoreferenced image.
## usage: tiler <input_image> <N> <E> <S> <W>
##

prefix=$(basename ${1%%.*})
N=$2
E=$3
S=$4
W=$5

# First, recover the image's dimensions.
IMG_CHARS=`identify "$1" | cut -f 3 -d' '`
xsize=`echo $IMG_CHARS | cut -d'x' -f 1`
ysize=`echo $IMG_CHARS | cut -d'x' -f 2`

# Insert georeferencing points, prepare for map projection.
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 0 0 $W $N -gcp $xsize 0 $E $N -gcp $xsize $ysize $E $S $1 ${prefix}.vrt

# Projection itself.
gdalwarp -of VRT -t_srs EPSG:4326 ${prefix}.vrt ${prefix}.vrt

# Create the tiles according to rules above.
gdal2tiles.py -t $prefix -p geodetic ${prefix}.vrt
```

UPDATE - I have followed the recommendations of the solutions below, but to no avail (see comments). Still, @Sorin is correct in his analysis.

This is the tree output of the first few levels of my base map tile hierarchy.

```bash
natural
├── 0
│   ├── 0
│   │   └── 0.png
│   └── 1
│       └── 0.png
├── 1
│   ├── 0
│   │   ├── 0.png
│   │   └── 1.png
│   ├── 1
│   │   ├── 0.png
│   │   └── 1.png
│   ├── 2
│   │   ├── 0.png
│   │   └── 1.png
│   └── 3
│       ├── 0.png
│       ├── 1.kml
.
.
.
```

As @Sorin said, the folders seem to have something wrong. For example, zoom 0 should only have one folder, the 0 folder, which only has one file, the 0.png file. Instead it has a 1 folder, which itself has another 0.png. Inspecting these files, I have come upon the other missing half of the map (0/1/0.png).

link [3]: developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out that it was the -p option in my gdal2tiles.py code. Openlayers and KML uses geodetic, while some others use mercator. So I simply tried that, and [voilá](http://cendas.lamce.ufr.br/Mapea/), it works. Apperantly, that's what leaflet.js prefers.

Essentially I switched:

```
gdal2tiles.py -t $prefix -p geodetic ${prefix}.vrt
```

for

```
gdal2tiles.py -t $prefix -p mercator ${prefix}.vrt
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet generally deals in the [Web Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) projection, while you've just tiled an Equirectangular-projected image. So, it doesn't work since equirectangular is a different project, and notably one that is twice as wide as it is tall. You can download [projected data from Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/), reproject it with GDAL to EPSG:900913, and render tiles that Leaflet can read.

Comment: That's odd, since according to http://leafletjs.com/features.html
support for 4326 is out of the box.

Comment: I have tried to reproject to 900913, but same problem is being exhibited.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you won't believe me, but your code is working well and your map is wrapping properly! (Of course, you can quit the wrapping effect by using `noWrap: true` in each tileLayer, but this isn't important now).

Looking at your tiles using `Developer Tools` (`Ctrl + Shift + I` in Chrome) I've noticed that  your tiles doesn't respect the XYZ tile addressing system:

[image]

Maybe my statement becomes evident when comparing your tile storage system with **[this](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/)**:

[image]

[image]

Now, all you have to do, I think, is to run `gdal2tiles.py` again, specifying the zoom level this time starting with 0, or to see if it is possible to only rename your tiles and folders.

Comment: I'll try that thanks. Will specify if it works ASAP.

Comment: Specifying zoom levels 0-5, didn't change anything.